# Format Jagged data gained from dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to format and extract some data from a database. While I can extract the data successfully I am struggling with the jagged nature of it.

What I have is the following:

```
create table temp
(
    QuestionID INT,
    AnswerID INT,
    AnswerValue NVARCHAR(50)
)

insert into temp values (1, 1, 'Ans C')
insert into temp values (1, 2, 'Ans B')
insert into temp values (1, 3, 'Ans A')
insert into temp values (2, 4, 'Ans D')
insert into temp values (2, 5, 'Ans E')

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.AnswerID) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT QuestionID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select QuestionID
                    , AnswerValue
                    , AnswerID
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(AnswerValue)
                for AnswerID in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table temp
```

Executed this produces

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| QuestionID |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|          1 | Ans C | Ans B | Ans A | NULL  | NULL  |
|          2 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | Ans D | Ans E |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I just need to format it like this

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| QuestionID |  Q1   |  Q2   |  Q3   |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
|          1 | Ans C | Ans B | Ans A |
|          2 | NULL  | Ans D | Ans E |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Note due to restrictions this needs to be done in SQL rather than an advanced language such as c#.

Comment: How about including your code that is giving you the wrong result?  Then we don't have to write code from scratch.

Comment: I am not looking for code more a suggestion on how to proceed.

In any case I will knock up some abstracted code as the actual queries are fiendishly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are wrong with the code. First, you are creating your column list using the `AnswerID` so the data is being split across multiple columns instead of the Answer for each question.

In order to fix this, you'll want to use a windowing function like `row_number()` to create a sequence for each question/answer combination.

When creating your dynamic columns change the code to be:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('Q'+cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
            FROM
            (
              SELECT rn = row_number() over(partition by QuestionID
                                             order by AnswerID) 
              FROM temp
            ) c
            group by rn
            order by rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

This will use row_number() and will create the column names based on the `QuestionID`.  Then you'll include the `row_number()` in your subquery making your code:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('Q'+cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
            FROM
            (
              SELECT rn = row_number() over(partition by QuestionID
                                             order by AnswerID) 
              FROM temp
            ) c
            group by rn
            order by rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT QuestionID, ' + @cols + ' 
           from 
           (
                select QuestionID
                  , AnswerValue
                  , col = ''Q''+ cast(row_number() over(partition by QuestionID
                                                         order by AnswerID) as varchar(10))
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(AnswerValue)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18def/6) This gives a result:

```
| QUESTIONID |    Q1 |    Q2 |     Q3 |
|------------|-------|-------|--------|
|          1 | Ans C | Ans B |  Ans A |
|          2 | Ans D | Ans E | (null) |
```

Comment: Ah use rownumber to autogenerate column titles. Fantastic that was just what I was looking for.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this part of code:

```
SELECT 'A' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY QuestionID ORDER BY Answer) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS cName
FROM tblAnswers
```

in order to generate the column names required. The above gives you sth like:

```
cName
-----
A1
A2
A3
A1
A2
```

You can subsequently use the above in your dynamic pivot to obtain the desired result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(a.cName) 
                   FROM (
                      SELECT 'A' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY QuestionID ORDER BY Answer) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS cName
                      FROM tblAnswers
                   ) a
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Question, ' + @cols + ' ' +
             'FROM (
                SELECT q.Question, a.Answer,
                       ''A'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.QuestionID ORDER BY Answer) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS cName
                FROM tblAnswers AS a
                INNER JOIN tblQuestions AS q ON a.QuestionID = q.QuestionID 
              ) t 
              PIVOT
              (
                 MAX(t.Answer)
                 FOR cName in (' + @cols + ')
              ) Pvt '

execute(@query)
```

Output from above looks like:

```
Question    A1      A2       A3
-----------------------------------
Q1          Answer1 Answer2 Answer3
Q2          Answer4 Answer5 NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3886d/4)